# Strange things with Pebble watch and Twitter for Android

Tags: android, twitter, pebble-watch, android-twitter

I have a strange behavior of Twitter client for Android with Pebble watch connected to phone.

When I stay at "Notifications" or "Direct messages" screens of Twitter and enter to menu or exit from menu on Pebble, I hear refreshing sound and appropriate animation "pull down to refresh".

Does anyone have some situation?

Comment: This looks like a bug report and not a programming question. Are you sure you're in the right place?

Comment: Not quite. But maybe you suggest best place for asking for competent people.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or whatever support channels that app offers.